# angularjs recursive ng-include not refreshing when onload variable changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

Given the example at:

http://jsfiddle.net/8LhJH/

The easiest way I can explain is with the interaction steps...

Problem case:

1. select Item 1, I see item1.items in box 2
2. select Item 2, I see item1.items in box 2 still!  (should be item2.items in box 2)

Functional case:

1. select Item 1, I see item1.items in box 2
2. select --Root--, which removes box 2
3. select Item 2, I see item2.items in box 2

I think the problem is somewhere with the ng-include recursion...

```
<div ng-if="level < path.length && path[level] && cItem.items[path[level]] && cItem.items[path[level]].items" ng-include="'item_select_recur.html'" onload="cItem=cItem.items[path[level]];level=level+1;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

http://jsfiddle.net/8LhJH/1/

The magic is in manually updating box 2's scope (see jsfiddle for complete example):

```
nextElement.scope().cItem = parentItem.items[$scope.path[level]];
```